# Counting characters in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function called `count_numbers` that takes in a list containing numbers and returns the count of numbers in the list. Your program has to cater to the possibility of having a list of numbers as element(s) in the input parameter.  You can assume that the input parameter is at the most a 2-dimensional list.

Here is the output when file is run calling the function as:

```
>>> print("Count of numbers", count_numbers([4,6,[1,2],10,[-1,-3]]))
Count of numbers:7
```

My answer i got was 5 instead of 7.
here is my working:

```
def count_numbers(numbers):
    result = []
    for element in numbers:
       for subelement in [element]:
           result += [subelement]
           results = len(result)
    return results
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i dont know how to get count of numbers = 7. My answer i get is 5.

Comment: Then give a properly formatted [mcve] to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

not quite sure what you what to do, but i guess this should work:

```
for elem in line:
  if type(elem) == int:
     result += 1
  elif type(elem) == list:
     for sub in elem:
        if type(sub) == int:
           result += 1
```

bear in mind that this code is realy ugly ;) but it should help get you started

Comment: add a duplicate to that list of numbers and your count will be off

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this manually, you are going to need to test the `type` of each `element`, to check if you are dealing with an `int` or a `list`, if a `list` you will have to create a deeper `loop`. After you `count` the element you will need to `append` it to a list, to check against so you don't count that same element again.

```
lst = [4,6,[1,2],10,[-1,-3]]

count = 0
seen = []
for i in lst:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        for j in i:
            if j not in seen:
                count += 1
                seen.append(j)
            else:
                pass
    else:
        if i not in seen:
            count += 1
            seen.append(i)
        else:
            pass

print(count)
```

You can flatten your list and use `collections.Counter` as well

```
from collections import Counter
lst = [4,6,[1,2],10,[-1,-3]]
new_lst = []

for i in lst:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        new_lst.extend(i)
    else:
        new_lst.append(i)

c = Counter(new_lst)
print(c) # Counter({4: 1, 6: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 10: 1, -1: 1, -3: 1})
print(sum(c.values())) # 7
```